# alignment problem in page bottom for paracol

Tags: alignment, paracol

I want typeset a book that have classic Chinese and morden Chinese, so I use `paracol` package. I already use command `\switchcolumn*` not `\switchcolumn`, but I found in some page, in page bottom, the left column and right column not alignment.

This is the problem in my project:
[image]

I hope the right paragraph can go down to next page, so they can alignment.

I find manually add `\clearpage` can solve this problem, but I don't want to solve like that, because there are many pages have this problem, i don't want to solve them all manually.

I try to make a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  includehead=true,
  top=2.6cm,
  left=2.3cm,
  bottom=2.6cm,
  right=2.3cm}

\def\txt{The quick brown fox.}
\newcount\n
\def\txts#1{\n=0
  \loop\ifnum\n<#1 \advance\n by1\txt\repeat}

\newcommand{\leftcol}{\switchcolumn[0]*}
\newcommand{\rightcol}{\switchcolumn[1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\leftcol\Large\txt
\rightcol\normalsize\txts{12}\vspace{18pt}

\leftcol\Large\txt
\rightcol\normalsize\txts{114}\vspace{18pt}

\leftcol\Large\txt
\rightcol\normalsize\txts{3}\vspace{18pt}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Because I typeset a huge book, so I need `nowidow` package to avoid widow line, and need the `vspace` between right column paragraph.

So how to solve this alignment problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is acceptable to you in your actual document:  `\newcommand{\rightcol}{\switchcolumn[1]\sloppy}`

Comment: If you use `\def\txt{The quick brown fox.\allowbreak}` then the first line will appear on the first page. (a space would be more realistic, but that chnges the page size.) I would simply add `\needspace{...}` (needspace package) for whatever minimum space looks good.

Answer (score 0):

This shows both of my suggestions.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{needspace}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  includehead=true,
  top=2.6cm,
  left=2.3cm,
  bottom=2.6cm,
  right=2.3cm}

\def\txt{The quick brown fox. }
\newcount\n
\def\txts#1{\n=0
  \loop\ifnum\n<#1 \advance\n by1\txt\repeat}

\newcommand{\leftcol}{\switchcolumn[0]*\needspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\rightcol}{\switchcolumn[1]\needspace{20pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\rightcol\rule{1pt}{54\baselineskip}

\leftcol\Large\txt
\rightcol\normalsize\txts{3}\vspace{18pt}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```